# urllib2.urlopen(url).read() fails to read the URL content

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am trying to read the web content of the link: `http://www.quikr.com/Mobile-Phones/y149` using following python command:

```
import requests
import urllib2
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'}
url = 'http://www.quikr.com/Mobile-Phones/y149'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

`print page` gives the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?Ref=/Mobile-Phones/y149&amp;distil_RID=97C53AFC-AA02-11E5-B76A-8C12C4D2AB6C&amp;distil_TID=20151224055301" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window){
        try {
            if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
                sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
            }
        } catch (e){}
    })(window);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/QkrDIV1cexsvzwdadarecara.js" defer></script><style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#qttwcrxueetv{display:none!important}</style></head>
<body>
<div id="distil_ident_block">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any workaround to get the actual url content to be read. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting the url in quotes?

Comment: just checked its a typo

Comment: I got the page's content using your code. I didn't get the output you are getting.

Comment: pretty strange. May I know what are you seeing after print page as I still get the same output pasted above

Comment: http://pastebin.com/idMsRAF1

Comment: thanks for sharing it works fine sometimes and sometimes it dont as the website identifies you as bot and sometimes do not. May be after a couple of hit it might give you the above described output failing which I am not able to automate the process of web scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to automate a real browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Working sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.quikr.com/Mobile-Phones/y149")

for phone in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".snb_entire_ad"):
    link = phone.find_element_by_css_selector("a.adttllnk")

    print link.text

driver.close()
```

If you want to get the page source, use [`.page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) (before closing the driver of course):

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I am running into an error of OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, using driver = webdriver.Firefox(). Trying to get this fix and would be able to test your solution.

Comment: this seems to display all the title relevant to each ads. However, I am looking to get the page source of URL's as using page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read() would give. Alternatively, would also like to hear your opinion as to why urllib2.urlopen("url").read() is not working for this url: http://www.quikr.com/Mobile-Phones/y149.

Comment: @Deepak okay, updated with how to get the page source.

Comment: driver.page_source gives me the page source I wanted but when I automate the process of scraping the website it tries to block me (thinking am a bot, which I am). Unable to get a workaround. 
As an alternative trying to add a delay in driver.get(url) might help.

Comment: @Deepak okay, what is happening - how are they trying to block you? Thanks.

Comment: after running the line driver.get(url) I get the browser opened up asking me to enter captcha to ensure am not a bot. Following which I get the actual page opened up

Comment: @Deepak it might be your past urllib attempts got you banned. Anyway, try adding delays or from a different IP, yeah. Thanks.